# Opções para Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, css3, safari, webkit

Olá,
Uso algumas classes CSS para alinhar objetos na tela:

```css
height: 65vh !important;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
justify-content: center;
```

Porém no Safari algumas dessas classes não funcionam no Safari.
Gostaria de saber qual opção para essas classes. Por exemplo, o código acima coloca a imagem no centro e na parte inferior da div, que tem o tamanho de 65% do viewport.
Se alguém puder me indicar um lugar para estudar essas questões já ajudaria bastante.
Obrigado

Comment: Essas propriedades funcionam a partir do Safari 10 de acordo com o site CanIUse.

Comment: Ok. Gostaria de saber a solução para navegadores Safari < 10. Obrigado

Comment: O flex é suportado à partir da versão 3.1 do Safari, porém utilizando o prefixo `-webkit-`. Veja mais no site do [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Outras propriedades, você pode pesquisar nesse site também. Já outra coisa a fazer, é criar outras classes que suportem _browsers_ antigos, o que vai lhe custar mais código para ter o mesmo efeito, porém irá funcionar. E outro detalhe, faça essa pergunta a você: "Eu realmente preciso suportar versões ultrapassadas do Safari?".